# Find $f,g$ such that $f \equiv g \mod 2i\pi $ has finitely many solutions

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm interested by two holomorphics functions $f,g : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ such that the set $$ E := \{z \in \mathbb C \mid e^{f(z)} = e^{g(z)} \}$$
is finite and non-empty.

For example : $f,g$ polynomials does not work because the equations $f-g=2i\pi k$ is all the time solvable. 
$f=z,g=e^z$ does not work also because there is an infinity of $w$ such that $e^w = w$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this equation has only finitely many solutions, then $f-g$ is an entire function omitting all but finitely many of the points $2\pi i k$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. By Picard's theorem this implies that $f-g$ is constant.